# Scrolling not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have a scroll function

```
$('#lisr').scroll( function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() +  $(this).innerHeight()>= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
    {
        //DO some code
    }
}
```

The problem is when I scroll down and it hits the bottom it executes the code twice instead of once, so If I make any ajax call in it, it is made twice, what I am missing in it?

Comment: Same result using `>` instead of `>=` ??? Or maybe `===`. Could you provide a jsfiddle otherwise

Comment: `scroll` event is fired many times, you should consider using throttling.

Comment: @undefined what is that? what does fb use?

Comment: @user1765876 He means debounce a little the scroll handler using a timeout for example

Comment: @A.Wolff > doesn't run the code and on == same result

Comment: @user1765876 this is obviously not possible, at least one condition must be reached, you are doing something else wrong. Because if '>=' pass, then '==' or '>' should pass too. If x >= y is true then x > y or x == y is true

Comment: @A.Wolff I said == gave same result as I told in my question means it make calls twice

Comment: @user1765876 sorry, misunderstood your statement. You should then check which values pass condition and set condition check according to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scroll()` function binds to the scroll event - which is fired many times when the user scrolls the page.

Write your code with the assumption that it can be called more than once:

```
var completed = false;

function doSomeCode() {}
function isAtBottomOfPage() {}

$('#lisr').scroll(function () {
  if (!completed && isAtBottomOfPage()) {
    doSomeCode();
    completed = true;
  } 
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZJ9k/1/

As a more advanced note, you probably shouldn't bind your logic directly to the `scroll` event; you run the risk of causing lag for your users when scrolling. Read more about this from John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: semaphores you mean in javascrip

Comment: @Wheelys seems like the code runs simultaneously.. as semaphores are not even helping

Comment: @user1765876 I can tell you with certainty that the code isn't happening simultaneously. See my updated answer for a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my codes for endless scrolling. What I do is unbinding the scroll event until the ajax request finishes. You can also use a variable as a flag and check/change its value before calling ajax request. Hope it helps:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', loadPage);
});


var loadPage = function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        $.ajax({
           //Your things here
           success: function(result){
              // Do success here
              $(window).bind('scroll', loadPage);
           },
           error : function(xhr){ //Do error here }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not the document height

Comment: I don't get what you mean? Document height is not exactly my point in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lisr').scroll( function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() +  $(this).innerHeight() > $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
    {
        //DO some code
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't satisying the if condition